# how to change the displaying description in the item

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".list-group").on("click", "a", function() {
        var title = $("#ttl2");
        var text = $("#txt2");
        title.text($(this).text());
        text.text("Description" + " " + ($(this).index() + 1));
      });
      $("#btnadd").on("click", function() {
        do {
          var msg = prompt("Add Title for the Item");
        } while (msg == null || msg == "");
        do {
          var msg4 = prompt("Add Descriprion to the Item");
        } while (msg4 == null || msg == "");
        var s = $("#ttl1");
        var h = $("#txt1");
        var app = $(".list-group").append("<a  class=list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item>" + msg);
        $("#btndeleteall").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#btndelete").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#btnedit").attr("disabled", false);
      });
      $(".list-group").on("click", "a", function() {
        var lii = $(this);
        $("#btnedit").on("click", function() {
          var s = $(".card-title");
          var h = $(".card-text");
          do {
            var msg1 = prompt("Edit the Title of the Item");
          } while (msg1 == null || msg1 == "");
          lii.text(msg1);
          s.text(msg1);
          do {
            var msg2 = prompt("Edit the Description of the Item");
          } while (msg2 == null || msg2 == "");
          h.text(msg4);
        });
      });
      $("#btndeleteall").on("click", function() {
        $(".list-group").empty();
        $(".card").css("width", "100%");
        $("#ttl2").text("There is no Item in the List");
        $(".card-text").text(" ");
        $("#btndeleteall").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btndelete").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btnedit").attr("disabled", true);
      });
      $(".list-group").on("click", "a", function() {
        var li = $(this);
        $("#btndelete").on("click", function() {
          li.remove();
          var len = $("a").length;
          if (len == 0) {
            $("#btndeleteall").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#btndelete").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#btnedit").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#ttl2").text("There is no Item in the List");
            $(".card-text").text(" ");

          }
          $(".list-group").trigger("click");

        });
      });
```

```css
.list-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  border-left: 5px solid aqua;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn-danger {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.card-title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.card-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item">List Item 10</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card card-primary card-inverse">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title" id="ttl2"><span>List Item</span><span id="result"> none</span></h4>
          <p class="card-text" id="txt2"><span>Description</span><span id="result1"> none</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnedit">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndelete">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndeleteall">DeleteAll</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with me that when I'm adding new Item to list with Title and description from prompt, and then clicking on it, it is displaying Title but displaying Description as default for example : Title that I put is hello and description world when i Click it it give me Title hello but description is description 11
and when I'm clicking Edit and changing title and description it give me same of button add
is the problem from function 1 and if it is what i need to change to solve this problem
[This is screenshot for the web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s14yW.png)

here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made most (if not all) of your function working.

Basically, the major change is to use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the descriptions.

Then, you were defining the click handlers for `#btnedit` and `#btnedit` at each `$(".list-group")` clicks... **and** using 3 different `.on()` methods. That needed to be cleaned... At least for readability.

Define you handlers independently and code it so it will not need to be redefined. The use of an `active` class really is usefull here to retrieve the clicked anchor.

Defining a handler within another one often (if not always) lead to issues or at least a noodle plate to unravel when it time to edit.

When you have redundant code chunks, make it a named function to call. I did it with `disabledButtons(bool)`, have a look.

An other major thing you should start doing right now is to use relevant classnames and variable names. Again, for readbility. It helps debugging a lot.

Haa... And I considered the `do{} while()` loops useless for the `prompts()`, which are halting the code execution here... Removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var title = $(".card-title .result");
  var description = $(".card-description .result");
    
  // LIST ITEM CLICK
  $(".list-group").on("click", "a", function() {
    title.text($(this).text());
    description.text($(this).data("description"));
    
    // Make this on active
    $(".list-group a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  
  
  // ADD AN ITEM
  $("#btnadd").on("click", function() {
    var prompt_title = prompt("Add Title for the Item");
    var prompt_description = prompt("Add Descriprion to the Item");
    
    // Added href='#' below
    var app = $(".list-group").append("<a href='#' class=list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item data-description='"+prompt_description+"'>" + prompt_title);
    disabledButtons(false);
  });
  
  
  // EDIT AN ITEM
  $("#btnedit").on("click", function() {
    if($(".active").length){
      var prompt_title = prompt("Edit the Title of the Item");
      var prompt_description = prompt("Edit the Description of the Item");
      
      $(".active").text(prompt_title).data("description",prompt_description);
      $(".active").trigger("click");
    }else{
      alert("Click an item first!");
    }
  });
    
  
  // DELETE ALL
  $("#btndeleteall").on("click", function() {
    $(".list-group").empty();
    $(".card").css("width", "100%");
    
    disabledButtons(true);
  });
  
  
  // DELETE THE ACTIVE
  $("#btndelete").on("click", function() {
    if($(".active").length){
      $(".active").remove();
      
      var len = $("a").length;
      if (len == 0) {
        disabledButtons(true);

      }else{
        title.text("List Item none");
        description.text("Description none");
      }
    }else{
      alert("Click an item first!");
    }
  });
  
  
  function disabledButtons(bool){
    $("#btndeleteall").attr("disabled", bool);
    $("#btndelete").attr("disabled", bool);
    $("#btnedit").attr("disabled", bool);
    
    if(bool){
      title.text("There is no Item in the List");
      description.text(" ");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.list-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  border-left: 5px solid aqua;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn-danger {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.card-title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.card-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 1">List Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 2">List Item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 3">List Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 4">List Item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 5">List Item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 6">List Item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 7">List Item 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 8">List Item 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 9">List Item 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item" data-description="Description 10">List Item 10</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card card-primary card-inverse">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title"><span>List Item: </span><span class="result"> none</span></h4>
          <p class="card-description"><span>Description: </span><span class="result"> none</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnedit">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndelete">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btndeleteall">DeleteAll</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```